# How to make infinite async requests every 10ms inside a loop?

Tags: python, loops, asynchronous, python-requests, request

Do I need to use threads too? I'm new to async, I was doing it creating 1 thread for every request that I wanted to do, but it was very "inefficient".

I want something like:

```
def async_request(i):
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body(i), timeout=5)
    r = response.json()
    if r['result'] > 50:
        do something

i = 0
while True:
    async_request(i)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(0.01) # 10 ms delay
```

I want to send the request every 10ms and I don't want to wait for one request response to send another, and after I receive the request inside the function "async_request" I want to do something with the result **instantly** if meet the requirements.

Comment: In principle you could start a new thread every ~10ms. However, what do you think is going to happen if the thread takes >10ms to execute?

Comment: The thread itself is going to take more than 10ms due to the request response time (5s in worst cenario), and I want to send requests to a lot of urls in my app, so I it will create too many threads, and the code seems very inefficient with threads taking longer than expected (10ms between requests) when running in a server.

Comment: If the thread takes >10ms and you create a new thread every ~10ms you will accumulate vast numbers of threads until such time as your computer explodes

Comment: No because the threads automatically end after max 5 seconds (500 threads max)

Answer (score -1):

I think that using async for your problem is a good idea. However, for this, you have to change multiple things. First of all, I would include `asyncio`, which lets you place tasks on the event loop for processing. Secondly, `aiohttp` for non-blocking HTTP requests. The following code uses both to achieve your goal of sending multiple requests in short intervals:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json


async def send_post_request(session, url, headers, body):
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers, data=body) as resp:
        json = await resp.json()
        return json


async def async_request(session, i):
    # TODO change to your params
    test_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
    body = json.dumps({'title': 'foo', 'body': 'bar', 'userId': i})
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

    result = await send_post_request(session, test_url, headers, body)

    # TODO process JSON result
    print(result)

async def main():
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    i = 0
    while True:
        # Add new request to your event loop
        loop.create_task(async_request(session, i))
        i += 1
        # TODO change sleeping period to what you want
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

P.S.: I used similar code in a project and noticed that you can clearly send more requests with `asyncio` than with traditional threads in a short amount of time.

Comment: I tried your code but it keeps printing {'userId': 1, 'id': 1,...
I think your i isnt incrementing?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that I always send the same request and it returns always the same result. You have to adapt the request for your specific use case. You can print `i` in the function `async_request` to see that it increments for every request.

Comment: I just get:   File "C:\Users\jbard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)

Comment: I am not familiar with your error. I just tested the code and it still works fine. If it helps I use version `3.8.1` for both `asyncio` and `aiohttp`. You could check if this is a problem. Otherwise, I would suggest opening a new question with your code, the full error message, and your versions.